# PyStackAPI - wrapper for the StackExchange API, written in Python

Tags: library, python

## PyStackAPI

The latest version - 0.2.0

### What is PyStackAPI?

PyStackAPI is a modern, 100% typed wrapper for the StackExchange API, written in Python.

### Documentation

You can find documentation here: https://pystackapi.gitbook.io/docs.

### Installing

Enter in terminal:

```sh
pip install git+https://github.com/wchistow/pystackapi.git@0.2.0
```

and that's all.

### Simple example

Code for getting general information about StackOverflow:

```python
from pystackapi import Site
from pystackapi.sites import StackOverflow

site = Site(StackOverflow)  # Creating a Site class for the StackOverflow site

info = site.get_info()  # Calling the necessary method

print(info.total_questions)  # Getting the necessary key
```

Output:

```
23908838
```

### Changelog

You can find the changelog for the PyStackAPI library in file [CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/wchistow/pystackapi/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

### License

MIT

### Links

- GitHub repository: https://github.com/wchistow/pystackapi.git
- Bug tracker: https://github.com/wchistow/pystackapi/issues
- Documentation: https://pystackapi.gitbook.io/docs